# Delay a link tag in html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I delay the firing of a link tag when calling the external resource.

```
<link href="externalresource.com">
```

I want this to be called after 5 seconds.

Comment: Please provide at least a good-faith [mre] for us to be able to even start to help

Comment: @CanO'Spam I am trying to load this <link href="externalresource.com"> after some delay time.

Comment: `<link href="` is for lots of things, not just stylesheets. Some more context would be useful. As would an attempt to do this. Typically if you don't want an element to do anything for a time, then don't add it to the DOM until you want it. You've tagged [tag:jquery] which is a library focused on changing the DOM. Doing things "after some time" in JS is quite trivial and easy to Google.

Comment: No. I am using link to connect to external resource. <link href="https://connect.facebook.net/">

Comment: Putting a time delay on a `preconnect` sounds like an extraordinarily pointless plan. "I want to do this **as soon as possible** but not for 5 seconds".

Answer (score 0):

You can put a delay on a function using `setTimeOut`

HTML:

```
<!-- we will set href using javascript/jquery -->
<link rel="stylesheet" />
```

Javascript:

```
// javascript will call the callback function after 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds)
setTimeout(() => {
  $("link").attr("href", "example.css");
}, 5000);
```

---

**Edit**: as [freedomn-m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2181514/freedomn-m) pointed out, this will change all of the `<link>` tags. In case you want to change a specific link, you can add `:eq(index)` to the end of the jquery selector to specify which link tag you want to select. e.g:

HTML:

```
<!-- we don't want javascript to change this tag -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test1.css" />

<!-- we want to change only this one -->
<link rel="stylesheet" />
```

Javascript:

```
// only select the second item (index = 1)
setTimeout(() => {
  $("link:eq(1)").attr("href", "example.css");
}, 5000);
```

Comment: You'll *probably* want to identify it somehow, otherwise this will change all `<link>` tags, including all your css.